# Blacklist the [learning] tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-block-request, meta-tags

As far as I can tell, [learning](/questions/tagged/learning) is an unnecessary meta tag that deserves to be **burninated**, especially [now that we're on a roll](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/102439/162705). Note that this tag [has been burninated before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93669/162705) and yet it still [refuses to die](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93735/162705). Let's put it out of its misery by blacklisting it, too.

Comment: Man, how many times will it be revived?  [I thought it was burninated back in June](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93735/do-we-really-need-the-learning-tag).

Comment: Heh, not only has it been revived, but it also has 154 questions and counting!

Comment: It was apparently removed many times before (before burninations became necessary).  I would have thought burnination now included blacklisting.  I hope we can make it official now.

Comment: That's a good point, @Jeff. Burnination should automatically result in blacklisting, shouldn't it? If not, would that be a reasonable feature request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok this tag is now blacklisted; any tag we destroy *that comes back from the dead*, needs to be blacklisted.