# What should I do with SO questions about learning or resources?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, meta-tags

While browsing the list of ruby questions with no other tags, I came across https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806/what-is-the-best-way-to-learn-ruby (53 upvotes, 46 favorites, 31 answers).

Obviously, I can't add [learning](/questions/tagged/learning) because that's been [burninated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93735/do-we-really-need-the-learning-tag) and [blacklisted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102178/blacklist-the-learning-tag) for Stack Overflow. What should I do?

1. Treat the question as not a good Stack Overflow question: ask it to be closed / deleted / marked as historical / [possibly maybe perhaps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-programmers-se-as-your-toilet-bowl) migrated.
2. Add [resource](/questions/tagged/resource) instead. Or is resource is too meta?

Related question: [Where do books & learning sources questions belong?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84033/where-do-books-learning-sources-questions-belong) , but that's from the perspective of someone asking a question.

**Update:** The question got closed as not constructive by ChrisF, and diamond mod Will.

Comment: Also somewhat related: [Old “best book/resource” questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107712/old-best-book-resource-questions)

Comment: @slugster: I seem to have a knack of asking questions related to questions asked less than 24 hours beforehand!

Comment: Your question is still valid, it is about tagging one of those posts. I simply linked my question because there is a drive on at the moment to clean up those questions, and the one you linked may end up dead as a dodo.

Comment: I would have thought migrating would be best, but I find questions get closed a lot more frequently over there. I'm actually disappointed that I can no longer treat StackOverflow as a single unified resource for finding answers to software/programming style questions. There's about 6/7 specific stack exchange sites now rather than 1. I much preferred a single, simple unified resource :(

Answer (score 7):

One super awesome thing I have seen done is [Antoras'](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/158003/antoras) https://stackoverflow.com/tags/scala/info

Imagine if Ruby had one of those, the old poor fit question would probably fit nicely in the tutorial and get much better visibility than trying to shoehorn a tag onto it.

Comment: It's AwesomeButImpractical. Most visitors wouldn't look at the "info" tab of a tag. As a side note, the "Learning Scala" question is closed.

Comment: RE: "Most visitors wouldn't look at the "info" tab of a tag." ... make it awesome, I will make sure it gets the traffic :)

Comment: Wow that is awesome.  It makes the wiki page functional too now.  All tags wikis should strive to be more like that.  I think it would be nice to have a dedicated tutorial tab just for that purpose.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm - For example, the Scala tag wiki was on the front page of HackerNews for several hours a couple days ago: http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=3037650 - I'm guessing *that* caused more than a couple visitors to look at the tag wiki.

Comment: @KevinVermeer: I don't read HackerNews. I want to get work done!

Comment: @AndrewGrimm - Do you realize that you have almost 5k rep on MSO?

Comment: @KevinVermeer: Touché. I was wondering if someone would come back with that retort!

Answer (score 1):

I always had the impression such 'Where can I learn ..' questions are very appropriate for the Programmers stack. Simply move (or propose a move) to there and the question is likely to be welcomed warmly.

Comment: Be careful. "What's the best way to learn X?" isn't a constructive question on any site. It will just get a list of people's favourite method which doesn't help the poster.

Comment: True I guess. It's just that I saw alot of similar questions being transferred to Programmers in the past, not necessarily with this exact sentence though.

Answer (score 0):

I would vote for a tag, or since everyone hates meta, a set of similarly named tags for these sorts of questions.

Why?  Because maybe I want an easy way of finding learning resources (or whatever synonym you prefer).  I want some place I can go and see everyone's glorious recommendations, instead of searching for tag:python and books, or whatever.

Yes, it would be ideal if each programming tag had this on the tag wiki, but maybe that's not a valid substitution.  Look at this question I just posted (please don't kill it!): [Learning C# and ASP.NET MVC for a Django/Pylons programmer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7589721/learning-c-and-asp-net-mvc-for-a-django-pylons-programmer).  I mean, that's fairly specific and maybe doesn't belong on a wiki.  More importantly finding curators for *everything* could be difficult.

So my vote is for something like `python-learning-resources` but for each language (I'm sure theres a more concise way of putting that), and for it not to get burninated.

Comment: I like these questions and prefer they're closed & locked with disclaimer rather than deleted, but they are _clearly_ off-topic, so we shouldn't be doing _anything_ to support them. Your question is included in that, although it looks like you might avoid the close/migration hammer this time. If they _were_ on topic, it would make more sense to tag them `python` and `whatever` (your first suggestion) than to create a joint tag -- that's why we have multiple tags.

Comment: @agf I totally agree with the latter, although there seems to be some dislike of 'meta' tags here, but maybe I'm just confused what counts as meta.  IMHO, 'on topic' appears to be slowly more redefined to mean 'a question about a bug in my specific program' (which helps no one but the poster) rather than what the FAQ says, which includes "software tools commonly used by programmers" and "matters that are unique to the programming profession." How are learning resources not included in those categories?

Comment: "Poll" questions are specifically considered off-topic. There is an example being discussed right now: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107932/dispute-closing-of-the-best-tail-gui-as-not-constructive

Comment: Note that the "not constructive" close reason also specifically mentions "polling".

Comment: @agf Fair enough... but I'd argue that there is a right answer for the best way to learn something, or at least answers that are right-er than others.  IMHO theres a continuum between that and "The best way to build something", "the best architecture", "Should I put images in the database".  I think figuring out how to learn something IS a programming problem.  Whether it belongs on SO or not, that's up to you pros, but certainly it should belong *somewhere*, it is constructive if you can actually have a debate and/or reach consensus.

Comment: For some Q's like that http://programmers.stackexchange.com is the place, but they have their own rules for what's on topic (and I don't use that site so can't advise you on them) so there are probably some questions that just don't fit into the SO model right now -- I think the debate / consensus thing doesn't quite fit in the straight-Q&A concept (except, of course, here on Meta, where voting indicates agreement / disagreement etc. far more than on the main sites).