# Dispute closing of "The Best Tail GUI" as not constructive

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons

I would like to dispute the fact of closing my question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133821/the-best-tail-gui as not constructive.

Logging is an essential tool for programmers all across the board and finding and picking the best tool for the job of monitoring and searching through live log files is certainly valuable knowledge.
The question was initially created to serve as a first hand repository of available best of the breed GUI logging tools on the market and has so far served it's purpose just fine.

The tooling advances over time and as new and better tools become available, I expect people to add to the list, so the topic could become a de-facto listing of available log file monitoring tools along with the optional ordering based on the popularity of the tool provided by people voting for their favorites.
This is a fairly old question (it's been there for couple of years now - asked Sep 25 '08) and there is almost none of the "argumentative" or "debatable" or "discussiony", in the answers so far.

I also believe that the potential usefulness of the answers over the time would be beneficial to all programmers as long as there is a continued need for a log monitoring software.

Please reopen the question as it seems to be closed a bit over zealously - only superficially considering the wording of a question instead of looking into it's long term impact.

Comment: It's a poll question -- there isn't a right answer.

Answer (score 15):

The question should remain closed because it is a Poll/List type question which is not welcome on Stack Overflow.

I am not sure why it is any different from questions such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173112/best-lightweight-ide-text-editor or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975/best-wysiwyg-css-editor

Please also see [the answer by Robert Cartaino](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98334/list-questions-community-wiki/98366#98366) on [List questions: Community Wiki?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98334/list-questions-community-wiki)

Answer (score 11):

May I quote from the [Frequently Asked Question of Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask):

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.
>
> ...
>
> To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …
>
> - every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”
> - your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”
> - there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”
> - we are being asked an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?”
> - it is a rant disguised as a question: “______ sucks, am I right?”

Your question

- does not have a definitive answer.
- is a poll question, and might need discussion.
- is subjective.

That it was closed now and not years ago has two reasons

- Stack Overflow has changed and has clearer rules now
- It has been overlooked until now

Comment: Okay, I can see the POV. I still believe that SO is the proper place for questions of this type. Would re-wording the question and creating a single accepted community wiki answer, raise the chance of re-opening the question as then it would not be about "polling" rather than providing up-to-date listing of available log Tail guis?

Comment: @Roland Tepp: No. It would still be subjective and a list-type. Additionally you can't keep it 100% up-to-date all the time. Such lists might be better suited at Wikipedia (if they want a separate list over there).

Comment: Well, frankly I have little faith in the Wikipedia in this matter.