# Should we have a "matlab-guide" tag for MATLAB's "GUI Layout Editor"?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are 109 questions tagged [guide](/questions/tagged/guide). A lot of the ask for "general help" on some topic, so I guess for those it is a [meta tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60166/what-tags-would-be-considered-meta-tags) and should be removed?

*But* there are also quite a number of questions with this tag which are actually about the [MATLAB GUI Layout Editor](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/guide.html), which happens to be called `guide`:

- [How can I instantiate one .fig file onto another in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445643/how-can-i-instantiate-one-fig-file-onto-another-in-matlab)
- [How to change MATLAB GUIDE figure callbacks file name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443957/how-to-change-matlab-guide-figure-callbacks-file-name)
- [Matlab: Superimposing a plot on an image in GUIDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203753/matlab-superimposing-a-plot-on-an-image-in-guide)

are recent examples.

I propose to create [matlab-guide](/questions/tagged/matlab-guide) with appropriate Wiki and retag the existing questions...

**Update**

I took the upvotes as a "yes" and went ahead with the change, now that I was able to do so myself ;-).

Comment: I think we should destroy `[guide]` altogether, because it is a meta-tag in my eyes. I'm all for your `[matlab-guide]` suggestion.

Comment: Is it necessary to tag [matlab-guide] separately from [matlab]?

Comment: @Nzbuu: I'm not sure I understand your question. If the question is about guide, I would put both tags [matlab-guide] and [matlab] personally...

Comment: My question is about whether tagging something as [matlab-guide] adds any value, given that it will almost always be tagged as [matlab] as well. I'm not necessarily saying it doesn't: I'm just trying to understand the rationale.

Comment: My rationale was that matlab-guide is a lot more helpful than [guide], so I'm trying to lull new users into rather using the former to avoid the latter; and you could imagine people filtering (positive or negative) using [matlab-guide].