# add a [howitworks] tag

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags

I recently asked a question on StackOverflow on [How decompiling works](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10311189/599402). I have noticed multiple other questions ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211270/how-does-traceroute-work), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684481/how-does-pex-work), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283257/how-does-jsfiddle-work), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046645/how-does-ror-cache-work), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216819/how-does-a-debugger-work), and many others) at different times, similar to this one -- they are asking how a particular process or concept works. It seems to me that these are some of the best questions on StackOverflow because they are not localized at all, and any visiting user can understand what is being said without having to take away its user-specific context.

I only have about 391 rep, so I'm a little while away from the 1500 rep required to create a tag. So I am proposing that there be a [howitworks](/questions/tagged/howitworks) tag created for questions like this (by someone other than me).

(Btw: I'm not sure whether it should be [howitworks](/questions/tagged/howitworks), [how-it-works](/questions/tagged/how-it-works), [howdoesitwork](/questions/tagged/howdoesitwork) or [how-does-it-work](/questions/tagged/how-does-it-work), etc. let me know which one you think is better, or if you think such a tag should even be created)

Comment: can someone just put a [declined] or [bydesign] tag, and stop downvoting? It is quite painful watching my rep going down like that!

Comment: *Sigh* [voting on meta is different](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences)

Comment: -1 for not reading the FAQ

Comment: @TheEstablishment - what FAQ are you referring to? I already knew how voting works here, however, if there is a [status-declined] tag, than there is no longer anything to disagree with because the post has been resolved, and therefore there is no longer any need to downvote. Regardless of what downvotes mean, I still don't like loosing reputation.

Comment: The FAQ about voting is the one. The presence or absence of tags has nothing to do with voting. Tags don't mean that a question is "resolved".

Comment: Can we just abolish reputation on meta altogether so people will quit whining?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn - until that happens, would you mind making this question a community wiki so I don't loose any more reputation??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[how-it-works](/questions/tagged/how-it-works) would be a meta tag, since it can't stand on its own, and thus is explicitly discouraged.

From [The Death of Meta Tags - Stack Exchange Blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/):

> ##From this point on, meta-tagging is explicitly discouraged.
> How can you tell you’re using a meta-tag? It’s easier than you might think.

> 1. **If the tag can’t work as the *only* tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag.** Every tag you use should be able to work, more or less, as the only tag on a question. Meta-tags, like [beginner], [subjective], and [best-practices], are useless by themselves — they tell you nothing at all about the content of the question.

> 1. **If the tag commonly means different things to different people, it’s probably a meta-tag.** In a cruel, ironic twist, the meaning of the tag [subjective] itself … is actually subjective. Ditto for [best-practices] and [beginner]. Best practices [to whom](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/04/best-practices-and-puffer-fish.html)? Beginner [by what criteria](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/10/defending-perpetual-intermediacy.html)? These tags are impossible to define by anything remotely resembling an objective metric. In comparison, the the meaning of tags like [java], [c#], and [javascript] are crystal clear to all but the nuttiest of nutbags.

Comment: why would it be a meta tag? why can't it stand on it's own? I have seen multiple questions on Stackoverflow it's self that were like this

Comment: It's a meta tag because it doesn't tell you anything about the question. A question tagged with howitworks would also need to be tagged with something else for the tag to make sense - in your example it would require both decompiling and howitworks.

Comment: As explained in the blog post, meta tags don't describe the **content** of the question. The tag [how-it-works] can't stand on its own, since a question tagged only as [how-it-works] could literally be about **anything**.

Comment: @Ephraim you might be interested in this discussion: [What tags would be considered “meta-tags”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60166/what-tags-would-be-considered-meta-tags) as well as in this SE blog post: [The Death of Meta Tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)

Comment: @Ephraim the point of tags is so people can filter by their expertise. This tag does not help filter, since you need to be familiar in a particular language to know how something works.